# Can't access phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

How can I access my phpMyAdmin. I got the following error message:

```
Error

MySQL said: Documentation
#2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

Comment: mysql default port is 3306 can you try changing  it and then try

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the solution is to stop all the services and solve the “Another daemon is already running” issue. I am assuming that you have installed it as in `/opt/lampp/lampp`

The commands you can try to solve the issue are as follows:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop              
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop    
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

You can also type instead:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service mysql stop
```

After that, we start again the `lampp` services:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Now, there must be no problems while opening:

```
http://localhost                  
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

Hope it will work..Answer could be more accurate if I would be able to have that attached screen short that you have not uploaded other then just caption.